# How to extract a certain string and delete rest of values from an input string?

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
INPUT="TEST: www.google.com TEST2: 123444 TEST3 Id: ABCD1234 TEST.txt"
```

My expected output is `ABCD1234`

I tried

```
OUTPUT=`echo $INPUT | sed 's/^.*TEST3 Id://' | sed 's/\[space].*//'`
```

Got this as output `ABCD1234 TEST.txt`

Comment: Are you looking for the space-delimited word after `TEST3 Id:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
echo "$INPUT" | sed 's/.*TEST3 Id: \([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

The `\( \)` is a useful construct that delimits the part of the regex that will be reproduced by `\1`. So it reproduces only the largest string without spaces beginning right after `TEST3 Id:`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, using a capturing group

```
sed 's/.*TEST3 Id: \(.*\) .*/\1/'
```

Test

```
echo "TEST: www.google.com TEST2: 123444 TEST3 Id: ABCD1234 TEST.txt" | sed 's/.*TEST3 Id: \(.*\) .*/\1/'
ABCD1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say you're limited to sed ...

`echo "$INPUT" | awk '{print $7}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with GNU `grep`:

```
echo "$INPUT" | grep -Po "(?<=Id:[[:blank:]]).*[[:blank:]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter Expanion.

```
INPUT="TEST: www.google.com TEST2: 123444 TEST3 Id: ABCD1234 TEST.txt"

INPUT="${INPUT% TEST*}"

echo "${INPUT##* }"
```

Command Substitution with a Here string and array.

```
INPUT="TEST: www.google.com TEST2: 123444 TEST3 Id: ABCD1234 TEST.txt"

OUTPUT=$(read -ra var <<< "$INPUT"; echo "${var[-2]}")

echo "$OUTPUT"
```

Awk.

```
INPUT="TEST: www.google.com TEST2: 123444 TEST3 Id: ABCD1234 TEST.txt"

echo "$INPUT" | awk '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

Or do what you did with sed

```
INPUT=$(echo "TEST: www.google.com TEST2: 123444 TEST3 Id: ABCD1234 TEST.txt" | awk '{print $(NF-1)}')
```